# MERN Stack - JWT token not saving in browser Cookies after deploying it to cyclic.sh and codesandbox

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, session-cookies, express-jwt

I have built a notes app on MERN stack, and am using JWT tokens for authentication and axios and cors for communication between frontend and backend. My front end is on codesandbox and my backend is deployed to cyclic.sh.

I built my application on localhost and it was working perfectly on localhost, JWT token was getting saved in browser cookies and used by application. But after deploying frontend to codesandbox and express server to cyclic.sh it isn't saving token in browser cookies anymore. On response of login/register, browser is receiving cookie but it's not saving to browser cookies.

here's my authController which handles login and register in server.

```
require("dotenv").config();
const UserModel = require("../Models/UserModel");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const maxAge = 3*24*60*60;


const createToken = (id) => {
    return jwt.sign({id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: maxAge
    })
} 

module.exports.register = async (req,res,next) => {
    try {
        const {firstName, lastName, email, password} = req.body;
        const user = await UserModel.create({firstName, lastName, email, password});
        const token = createToken(user._id);

        res.cookie("jwt",token,{
            withCredentials: true,
            httpOnly: false,
            maxAge: maxAge * 1000,
            sameSite: "none",
            secure: true
        })
        res.status(201).json({user:user._id, created: true})
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        const errors = handleErrors(err);
        res.json({errors, created: false})
    }
};

module.exports.login = async (req,res,next) => {
  const { email, password} = req.body;
      try {
        const user = await UserModel.login(email, password);

        const token = createToken(user._id);

        res.cookie("jwt", token, { httpOnly: false, maxAge: maxAge * 1000, sameSite: "none", secure: true });
        res.status(200).json({ user: user._id, status: true });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        const errors = handleErrors(err);
        res.json({errors, status: false})
    }
};
```

Here's my login/register axios function

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "https://dark-pear-bandicoot-robe.cyclic.app/login",
        {
          ...values
        },
        {
          withCredentials: true
        }
      );
      if (data) {
        if (data.errors) {
          const { email, password } = data.errors;
          if (email) generateError(email);
          else if (password) generateError(password);
        } else {
          navigate("/");
        }
      }
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    }
  };
```

Thanks for the help in advance! :)